# wxPython, missing taskbar (not tray) icon, and top level windows

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I have a wxpython app, in the init function for the main application frame I create 2 dialogs, the first is a splash screen and the second is a login dialog. During the startup of my app, the splash screen is displayed, app init stuff happens, and the splash screen disappears before showing the login dialog. After logging in, the login dialog is hidden and the main app is shown. The problem is that the task bar entry and icon disappears when the login dialog is visible, it shows normally when the splash or main app is visible. I am talking about the main taskbar entry, not a system tray icon. What am I missing?

Comment: Please add your code so we can look at the issue.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see this [code of a wxPython application](https://pastebin.com/pn86mFiK))